# ¿Cual es el beneficio de usar interfaces para los servicios en Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente repositorio de JPA:

```
public interface IGreetingRepository extends JpaRepository<Greeting, Long> {
}
```

Y según la documentación tendría que generar una interfaz del servicio como sigue:

```
public interface IGreetingService {

    Greeting getGreetingById(Long id);

    List<Greeting> getAllGreetings();

    Greeting saveGreeting(Greeting greeting);

    void deleteGreeting(Long id);

}
```

Y despues la implenentación:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("greetingService")
public class GreetingServiceImpl implements IGreetingService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("greetingRepository")
    IGreetingRepository greetingRepository;

    @Override
    public Greeting getGreetingById(Long id) {
        return greetingRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Greeting> getAllGreetings() {
        return greetingRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Greeting saveGreeting(Greeting greeting) {
        return greetingRepository.save(greeting);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteGreeting(Long id) {
        greetingRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Y para hacer uso de mi servicio en mis controllers lo inyectaría asi:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("greetingService")
GreetingService greetingService;
```

Lo que no entiendo es, ¿cuál es la ventaja de hacerlo así en vez de inyectar directamente la interfaz del repositorio JPA y ahorrarme las 2 clases?:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("greetingRepository")
IGreetingRepository greetingRepository;
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es en realidad *¿Cuál es el beneficio de usar interfaces?*. Un caso es el del uso de Spring y un repositorio de datos como JPA. Pero las interfaces no están restringidas solo a Spring, sino que interfaz es un concepto más amplio y aplica para muchos lenguajes de programación. Quizás podrías reformular la pregunta a algo como [esta en stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las interfaces tienen varias ventajas:

**Abstracción**

Una interfaz es como un contrato. El servicio que implementa una interfaz está obligado a ofrecer una serie de métodos con firmas bien definidas. Cualquier servicio que quiera cumplir con la interfaz tendrá que tener obligatoriamente un conjunto determinado de elementos. Esto te permite conectarte a diferentes servicios usando el mismo cliente.

**Usabilidad**

Si tu servicio implementa una interfaz, podrías reescribirlo completamente (o sustituirlo por otro distinto) y los clientes podrían seguir consumiendo tu servicio sin problemas. Ellos a lo sumo notarán diferencias en el rendimiento, pero poco más.

**Seguridad**

Una interfaz representa únicamente una declaración de intenciones. No aparece código por ninguna parte. Al exponer una interfaz no estás comprometiendo el código fuente del servicio.

**Mantenimiento**

Si un servicio expone una interfaz tu entorno de desarrollo puede verificar fácilmente que una nueva versión del servicio cumple (al menos) con los requisitos expuestos en la interfaz. Es una forma sencilla de automatizar un proceso que evita que se te *olvide* implementar parte de la funcionalidad. Esta característica suele mejorar el índice de mantenimiento de los proyectos.

Con todo esto, parece casi evidente que es una buena práctica exponer interfaces siempre que sea posible. Que un sistema como spring te obligue a exponer interfaces en vez de implementaciones es una buena noticia para tu servicio.

Comment: Gracias, muy buena explicación

Comment: @jhonnyvargas La pregunta no trata sobre si se pueden usar o no interfaces sino sobre las ventajas de estas últimas. No entiendo tu intento de edición